# не рисуется линия в Swing!

Tags: java, swing

Только на чал изучать Swing. Написал простенький код, чтобы в окне рисовать двумерные фигуры (в моем случае это линия). Но не могу понять, почему она не строится. Подскажите, где ошибка?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setTitle("figures");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(600,400));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GraphicsPanel graphicsPanel = new GraphicsPanel();

        frame.add(graphicsPanel, new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,1,1,1,
                GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                new Insets(2,2,2,2),0,0));

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}







  import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
    import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
    import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

        public class Line extends Line2D{

            private Point p1;
            private Point p2;

            public Line()
            {
                p1 = new Point();
                p2 = new Point();
            }

            public Line(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
                p1 = new Point (x1, y1);
                p2 = new Point (x2, y2);
            }

            @Override
            public double getX1() {
                return p1.getX();
            }

            @Override
            public double getX2() {
                return p2.getX();
            }

            @Override
            public double getY1() {
                return p1.getY();
            }

            @Override
            public double getY2() {
                return p2.getY();
            }

            @Override
            public Point2D getP2() {
                return p1;
            }

            @Override
            public Point2D getP1() {
                return p2;
            }

            @Override
            public void setLine(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
                p1.setLocation(x1,y1);
                p2.setLocation(x2,y2);
            }

            @Override
            public Rectangle2D getBounds2D() {
                return null;
            }
        }



import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel{

    private Line line;

    public GraphicsPanel()
    {
        line = new Line(10,20,300,400);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.draw(line);
    }

}
```

вот результат работы программы
[image: результат]
так же еще есть класс определением точки, унаследованный от класса Point2D. Там переопределены все методы, думаю, что ошибок в нем нет.

Comment: Попробуй PaintComponent вместо PaintComponents, просто убери окончание 's'

Comment: @НиколайБеляков да, все заработало. Огромное спасибо!!